# Не работает move_uploaded_file в php

Tags: php

```
$dir = dirname(__FILE__) . '\\' . $_FILES['inputfile']['name'];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['inputfile']['tmp_name'], $dir);
```

Comment: что конкретно не работает, модно подробнее, прилодите распечатку переменной $_FILES, покажите соответствующие раздела phpinfo

Comment: Проверьте логи, и дирекрорию `tmp`, возможно `move_uploaded_file` пытается передвинуть файл в директорию, которой нет.

Comment: Файл не перемещается, а папка есть

Comment: `Array ( [inputfile] => Array ( [name] => test.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => C:\PHP\UpLoad\php1A94.tmp [error] => 0 [size] => 24875 ) )`

Comment: А что в логах пишет?

Comment: Запешите статичный путь в `$dir` И проверьте.

Comment: зачем после полного пути, пишите 2 слеша, а потом имя файла? За место 2-х слешей, напишите `DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR`, если используете php 5.3 и выше, за место `dirname`, используйте `__DIR__`.

Comment: Обычно такая ошибка бывает из неправильного пути или отсутствия прав записи в директорию

Comment: А как получить права на запись?

Comment: [12-May-2018 22:28:00 Asia/Kuwait] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move 'C:\Upload\php89F0.tmp' to 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\file\test.jpg' in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\file\index.php on line 9